# Unable to Position Drop down correct in Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Taking code directly from the Bootstrap 4 page (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/), I have the dropdown positioned / setup and working, however the dropdown box positions to the far left of the page instead of directly beneath the button. Not sure why. Anyone know what I should do to fix this? JSFiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/1m0g2fvh/

Associated html using standard bootstrap 4:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle bg-inverse" style="border:none;" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" >
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class to parent li `dropdown`

Wrap the dropdown’s trigger and the dropdown menu within `.dropdown`, or another element that declares `position: relative;`. Then, add the menu’s HTML.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1m0g2fvh/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle bg-inverse" style="border:none;" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" >
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/1m0g2fvh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for Bootstrap, they say alignment of the dropdown menu needs to be aligned with CSS. I tried this and it works

`.dropdown-menu{
  margin-left:20%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this add this style

```
   .navbar-nav .nav-item+.nav-item{position:relative}
```

it is working